# Finding closest number in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an unordered array of objects

```
[{id:1, time_in: 2},{id:4, time_in: 10},{id:4, time_in: 6}.{id:4, time_in: 25},{id:4, time_in: 14}]
```

I want to check which element of this array has "time_in" closest to a given number, say 17.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Create a 2nd array using `.map()` that has the difference as elements. Then find the index of its minimum. You can probably do it in a single step using `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a check for the smaller absolute delta of the value and the wanted value and return the object with the smaller one.

For getting a smaller value than the pivot add another check in front of the absolute check.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, time_in: 2 }, { id: 4, time_in: 10 }, { id: 4, time_in: 6 }, { id: 4, time_in: 25 }, { id: 4, time_in: 14 }],
    pivot = 17,
    result = data.reduce((a, b) => 
        a.time_in <= pivot && Math.abs(a.time_in - pivot) < Math.abs(b.time_in - pivot)
            ? a
            : b
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works. Can u tell me what should I change in this to get the closest smaller value in the array with respect to pivot

Comment: @EdG, do you have an example?

Comment: Yes. So consider that var data = [{ id: 1, time_in: 2 }, { id: 4, time_in: 10 }, { id: 4, time_in: 6 }, { id: 4, time_in: 18 }, { id: 4, time_in: 14 }]  and pivot is same "17".

In this case the "result" should be "14" and not "18"

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the array and subtract the time_in field with the number that you want close to it. Find the absolute of the result and the smallest absolute result is your object with the closest time_in.

Example:

```
const findCLosestField = (arr, closestNumber) => {
  let closeBy = Math.abs(arr[0].time_in - closestNumber)
  let closeByIndex = 0
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    let currentClosest = Math.abs(arr[i].time_in - closestNumber)
    if(closeBy > currentClosest){
      closeBy = currentClosest
      closeByIndex = i
    } 
  }

  return arr[closeByIndex]
}
```

However, there is a few things you will need t to consider like if you have a time_in 16 and a time_in 18. They both are closer to 17 for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
let res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const delta = Math.abs(curr.time_in - x)
  return delta < acc.delta ? { curr, delta } : acc
}, { ...data[0], delta: Math.abs(data[0].time_in - x) })
```

Answer (score -1):

Array.reduce is probably the easiest way. Try this:

```
const a = [
  { id: 1, timeIn: 2 },
  { id: 4, timeIn: 10 },
  { id: 14, timeIn: 6 },
  { id: 24, timeIn: 25 },
  { id: 34, timeIn: 14 }
];

const difference = (a,b) => Math.abs(a-b);

function closest(timeIn, entries) {
  return entries.reduce((accum, entry) => {
    return difference(timeIn,accum.timeIn) < difference(timeIn,entry.timeIn) ? accum : entry;
  });
}

console.log("result", closest(15, a));
console.log("result", closest(6, a));
console.log("result", closest(-1, a));
console.log("result", closest(100, a));
console.log("result", closest(32, a));
```